# why does my truck shake when I go 35 miles an hour down the road?

Tags: toyota, tires, vibration, truck

I am running 38s on my Toyota 1984 and I think it shakes because i mean i am running 38's on a Toyota but also that maybe they are out of alignment or that they are just low but im not sure...

Comment: Did it vibrate before the 38's were installed?

Comment: sometimes, but not as much as recently.. but i mean i need to get it figured out because its sketchy driving it to highschool with a death wobble and no doors but you can also power through if you pass up 35.. so idk whats wrong @mikes

Answer (score 1):

If you can "power through" then you should get the hub bearings checked for excessive play as this can cause the symptoms you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If it was there before the tire swap, something is worn loose, bent or out of alignment. It is likely exaggerated by the oversize tires. Start with the basics. Check for loose tie rod ends, ball joints etc. Some of the Toyota forums reference loose spring shackles as a cause. On a vehicle that old anything could be worn out, spring bushings, wheel bearings, track rod/torque arm bushings etc. I would suggest seeing if you can get an alignment, a reputable shop will tell you what is worn before doing the alignment. Most importantly stop driving it until you get it resolved. With oversized tires and an elevated center of gravity add unstable steering a rollover is in your future.